# Automatically detect unused code and exclude it from wheel build

Tags: python, dependency-management, python-wheel

I have a large(ish) python library that does a lot of inter-related stuff (training some neural networks, setting up datasets, testing, evaluation, running inference on the networks, etc.). I want to build an extremely lightweight cut-down bare bones wheel package, which would only allow running of the inference and a few related things, all in all I only need to call maybe 5 different functions. This would have fewer deps and other benefits (not the least a faster start time).

I started doing this by hand, by specifying only the necessary packages and removing the no-longer needed imports via `sed` in my build script. But this isn't very scalable at all, as soon as I make any changes to the files affected, the build script will need to be updated.

I've been reading up on tools such as Vulture, which would do static code analysis and show me dead code branches, but it's not quite what I need. For one, there are many CLI scripts which are not used (and which won't be discovered), and for the other the results are not immediately usable, I would still need to build something around it.

I cannot believe there isn't a tool to do this. What I'm after is specifying a bunch of functions (as imports?) and getting out the minimum amount of code that is needed to run those successfully. Of course I could build something of that sort, but that feels like reinventing the wheel. Is there a tool out there which I could either just use, or possibly bend to my needs? Thanks!

Comment: Here is a manual approach. I feel the effort is worth it, to accomplish your admirable goal of Ship No Bloat! Create a pair of packages, maybe "core" and "explore", one depending on the other. Write unit tests for core, measure with `pytest --cov --cov-report=term-missing`, obtain "good" coverage. Then ship core. If you find a core routine is "hard to cover" or has just generally become superfluous, refactor so it is ejected, banished to the explore package.